# How can you change what the password prompt says in Django-Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

In django-tastypie when I have BasicAuthentication enabled my browser pops up a password prompt that says:

> The site says "django-tastypie"

Naturally, I want something better in there, but I'm not sure if it's a WSGI configuration or something else. How do I change what "the site says"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by setting the `realm` for BasicAuthentication. In your code you'll want to do something like:

```
class Meta:
    authentication = BasicAuthentication(realm="your-website.com")
```

Simple as that.